# How can I implement a summatory with a cycle and recurssion

Tags: python, recursion, addition, cycle

If i had this function

```
def P(n):
    iterador = 0
    while ( iterador <= n ):
        print(iterador)
        iterador = iterador + 1
P(8)
```

Which prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

What would I have to do, in order to add each number, like this

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36
```

I know it would be something like:

```
P(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 +...+ n

P(1) = 1
P(2) = P(1) + 2
P(3) = P(2) + 3
.
.
.
```

**P(n) = P(n-1) + n**

But I don't know how to put it into code.

Could someone give me a hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first step in recursion is using recursion. That means the function has to call itself somewhere. The next step in using recursion is stopping the recursion. That means providing a way for the function to stop calling itself when it's time to return a result. For this function, you'll want to start at the given number, then add it to number-1, then add that to the smaller number-1, and so on, until you get to 0.

```
def adder(n):
    if n:
        return n + adder(n-1)
    return n
```

If we pass this the value `8`, then `if n:` is true and we'll run that block. That means we'll return `8` plus the value of `adder(n-1)`, which is `adder(7)`. That returns `7` plus `adder(6)`, and so on. When `n` is `0`, it simply returns that. That means we have `n + adder(n-1) + adder(n-2)... 0`, which is the algorithm we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for your help, everybody. I applied the aforementioned, this is the result:

```
def P(n):
    if ( (n == 0) ):
        resultado = 0
    if ( ( n==1 ) ):
        resultado = 1
    if ( (n>1) ):
        resultado = P(n-1) + n
    return resultado

def Q(n):
    resultado = ( n*(n+1) // 2)
    return resultado

def F(n):
    serie = []
    for x in range ( 0, n + 1 ):
        serie.append(x)
    print(serie)

n = 8
print(P(n))
print(Q(n))
F(n)
```